# how to pass credentials to my database connection class?

Tags: node.js, oop, credentials

I’m building small API for university project and I am using NodeJS. The technology that I am using doesn’t really matter in this case, the problem is more general.
I have the following set of files and classes:
Index.js creates an instance of RequestHandler class.
RequestHandler instance has as instance of PropertiesStorage class.
Finally PropertiesStorage has an instance of DatabaseAccessor.

All these classes were created by myself, I wanted to create some logical abstraction layers, I think that’s a recommended approach. DatabasaAccessor makes use of database’s provider SDK. This SDK requires some credentials (database id, etc.)
So I need to pass these credentials to DatabaseAccessor somehow. I see two solutions, but both are not perfect in my opinion. Credentials are stored in config.js file. 
My ideas:
1. Load config.js inside of DatabaseAccessor - this seems to be a good solution, but then DatabaseAccessor becomes a little bit too dependent on the location and structure of this file, I think this class should be more reusable,
2. Pass the credentials starting from index.js and ending on DatabaseAccessor (through constructors of each of my classes) - I don’t like this, because the in-between classes become connected strongly with my database implementation. Again, I’d like each class to be reusable, even if I change my database provider or type in the future. I’d like to have an interface like IDatabaseAccessor and each implementation of it would have a different set of credentials probably.

What can you advice me? I’d really like to learn good practices in such cases.
I tried to find some solution on the internet, but I only found some questions about injecting credentials to Jenkins (which I don’t even know what it is).

Comment: you can use a `.env` file to store credentials. Load this .env and you can access these variables anywhere using `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`.

Comment: @itaintme Your proposal is just another way to store the credentials, I used config.js. Where do you think I should load this file? Inside of DatabaseAccessor?

Comment: Usually `.env` (environment variables) are used to store sensitive information such as database password, secret_access_keys, app_ids etc. In the apps I make, I load these up in environment variables in my `server/app.js` and then use them directly where needed using `process.env.VAR_NAME`.

So, you can load up `.env` in the `server.js` and use it wherever needed. Have a look at [this starter by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter) It'll give you a good idea about usage.

Comment: Also note that you don't really have to "pass" any credentials to any file, NodeJS returns the current state of each module in each import. So once you init the database, everywhere you import your database_helper.js, the same state will me imported.

Comment: Thanks @itaintme, your explanation really helped me, I will follow your suggestion. If you care about SO points, add your comment as an answer and I’ll accept it of course. About your last comment, could you please be more specific? I don’t really know what you mean. All modules I created are basically classes (I export a class in each module). When I import any of them I create a new instance. I think your comment was about modules that contain some variables and functions. It doesn’t apply to my situation I think

Comment: It does apply to classes as well @Loreno How are you creating classes? Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: @itaintme I plan to use TypeScript, but I'll do it when my project is finished. The less dependencies and steps in-between, the better for now. I'm creating classes with ES6 syntax (class MyClass {} ). To export my module I do: module.exports = MyClass. Then, in other files I just require this module and do: let myClass = new MyClass(). So, in this case, the state is not retained between different files, because I create new instance each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `.env` (environment variables) are used to store sensitive information such as database password, secret_access_keys, app_ids etc. It is recommended to load these up in environment variables in `server/app.js` and then use them directly where needed using `process.env.VAR_NAME`. So, you can load up `.env` in the `server.js` and use it wherever needed. Have a look at [this starter by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter) It'll give you a good idea about usage.

You can use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to load `.env` easily.